# How to write the values in files with different extensions by using the below code?

Tags: fortran

```
subroutine iswap (file,b)
 implicit none
 integer  b,m
 character*(*) file
 m=1
 do while (file(m:).ne.' ')
    m=m+1
 enddo
 m=m-1
 open(1, File = file(1:m),form='formatted')
 write (1,*) b
 close(1)
 end

 subroutine iswap1 (file,b1,c1)
 implicit none
 integer m,b1,c1
 character*6 file
 m=1
 do while (file(m:).ne.' ')
    m=m+1
 enddo
 m=m-1
 call iswap(file(1:m)//'.jk',b1)
 call iswap(file(1:m)//'.bk',c1)
 end

 program callex
 implicit none
 character*6  unit
 call iswap1(unit,2,3)
 end
```

I'm trying to write the code that generates two files ".jk" and ".bk", each containing the value 2 and 3. The code I wrote is not not creating any file. Could you please guide me in correcting this code keeping the code format same? The main program calls "iswap1" subroutine, which then calls "iswap2" subroutine that writes values to files with the extension mentioned in "iswap1" subroutine. Thanks!

Comment: This is a long way from idomatic Fortran code (those DO WHILE loops seem entirely needless, given the availability of `TRIM` and trailing blanks being insignificant in filenames), but the most obvious aspect is that you haven't defined `unit` in the main program, so every access from there is illegal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain how to use TRIM here? I'm new to fortran so don't know much. How to define unit? I did but getting Error: Symbol 'qwerty' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type error.

Comment: To define `unit` you'll need something like `unit=""` (for the empty string, so that your files are `.jk` and `.bk`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code roughly written in idiomatic modern Fortran:

```
program callex
 implicit none
 character(len=80) :: fname = "thefile"
 call iswap1(fname,2,3)
contains

  subroutine iswap (file,b)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in)  :: b
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: file
    integer :: unit
    open(newunit=unit, File = file ,form='formatted')
    write (unit,*) b
    close(unit)
  end subroutine iswap
  
  subroutine iswap1 (file,b1,c1)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: b1,c1
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: file
    call iswap(trim(file)//'.jk',b1)
    call iswap(trim(file)//'.bk',c1)
  end subroutine iswap1  

end program callex
```

Some notable changes from your original version:

- Use contained procedures to get argument checking.
- character variables declared with length per modern syntax.
- Initial character variable, `fname` initialized (and made a bit longer because why not). Also I initialized `fname` to a non-empty string because otherwise on Unix type systems the generated files will be hidden as the name would start with `.`.
- Dummy character variables declared with `len=*` meaning they get the length from the caller.
- Declare `intent` for dummy arguments.
- Use trim instead of a loop to get rid of trailing spaces.
- Use `NEWUNIT=` when opening units rather than manually allocating unit numbers.